# Проблема с активацией листа в VBA Эксель

Tags: vba

Здравствуйте, форумчане! Есть экселевский файл с двумя вкладками. При двойном клике на ячейке в первой вкладке появляется форма, отображающая некие данные. На форме две кнопки. При нажатии на одну форма просто закрывается и здесь проблем нет. При нажатии на вторую запускается макрос поиска ячейки на втором листе. Ячейка находится, выводится на середину экрана, второй лист с найденной ячейкой активируется, форма закрывается. И здесь начинается самое интересное и непонятное. При попытке прокрутить лист колесом прокрутки, ничего не происходит. Ячейки не перемещаются ни вверх, ни вниз. Причем полоса прокрутки на вращение колеса реагирует и перемещение ячеек происходит на первом листе, который в данный момент не показан на экране. Как только щелкаю мышью на первом листе, а потом возвращаюсь на второй, работа восстанавливается. Файл здесь:https://cloud.mail.ru/public/7Tms/2wH2Wznrb

Comment: Нужно видеть, как Вы переходите с листа на лист, код посмотреть...  Покажите пример.

Comment: Изменена тема и добавлена ссылка на файл. Если будут нужны пояснения - пишите.

Comment: @vikttur, спасибо за замечания. Расти, действительно, есть куда. Не понимаю, почему у Вас не проявляется ошибка. Испытал файл на нескольких компьютерах — везде одно и тоже. Т.к. при двойном клике ячейка переходит в режим редактирования, то есть подозрение, что именно этот режим ячейки мешает работать с листом, который активирован программно, а не через клик мышью. Есть ли способ программного выхода из режима редактирования ячейки?

Comment: Сначала перехват события, уже потом, если события нет, переход в режим редактирования. И, кстати - в режиме редактирования ячейки  невозможно запустить макрос. Попробуйте изменить свой код по рекомендациям. Возможно, попустит.

Comment: Еще догадка: шалит *Excel*, вернее, его версия. 2016 иногда преподносит сюрпризы. Я работаю в *Excel-2010*

Comment: @vikttur, попробовал файл в 2010 офисе — работает на УРА! Но т.к. на работе уже 2016-й — буду искать обходную дорогу.

Comment: Первым делом исправляйте код

Comment: @vikttur, код, согласно Ваших рекомендаций, исправил. За исключением удаления строк в листе "отчет" (доработаю позже т.к. в нем необходимо форматировать ячейки) и Прогресбара. Вышеуказанная проблема остается и скорее всего так просто не исчезнет. Здесь https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Cwhp/jewaAM72K лежит файл, упрощенный до минимума, который также не хочет работать в 2013 и 2016 Офисах.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить *DoubleClick* на *Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)*

Comment: @vikttur, тоже нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка не воспроизводится. Похоже на недостаток видеопамяти, да и памяти вообще.

**Грубая ошибка**:

переменная в процедуре

```
Dim wh_Sheet2612 As Worksheet
```

глобальная переменная

```
Public wh_Sheet2612 As Worksheet
```

Найдите различия... Переменные уровня процедуры могут иметь одинаковые имена в разных процедурах, уровня модуля - в разных модулях... Но нельзя давать переменным одинаковое имя, если эти переменные пересекаются!

**Кушаем память**.

Много лишних присвоений, без которых можно спокойно обойтись.

```
Set переменная = объект
```

Эта строка выделяет область памяти для хранения объекта. Если после использования память принудительно не освобождать, область **может остаться занятой**. Чем больше присвоений, тем больше памяти отрезается. Поэтому после отработки основной части кода память обязательно нужно освобождать

```
Set переменная = Nothing
```

**Переменные уровня процедуры**. Занимают память до завершения работы процедуры.

**Публичные переменные** (*Public*). Занимают память при открытии книги и освобождают ее только после закрытия. Если можно обойтись, лучше не применять.

Например, передача номера искомого вагона в процедуру поиска. Публичная переменная не нужна, значение можно передать в процедуру:

```
Private Sub cb_2612_Click()
    FindNumber.Поиск_ячейки_с_номером_вагона (ActiveCell.Value)
    Unload MsgForm
End Sub
```

Сам **поиск можно облегчить**, по минимуму занимая память (в Вашем варианте активирование листа происходит два раза; в переменные загоняются три объекта; для номеров последней и искомой строки можно использовать одну переменную):

```
' номер вагона передаем прямо в процедуру'
Sub Поиск_ячейки_с_номером_вагона(sNum As String)
    Dim int_Row As Long

    With Sheets("2612")
        ' определяем последнюю заполненную строку'
        int_Row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If int_Row < 2 Then MsgBox "Нет данных", 64, "УВЫ!": Exit Sub

        ' ищем в диапазоне номер вагона'
        int_Row = .Range("A2:A" & int_Row).Find(What:=sNum, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True).Row

        .Activate ' активируем лист'
        .Cells(int_Row, 1).Activate ' активируем строку с номером вагона'
    End With
End Sub
```

Поиск происходит быстро, зачем Вам *ProgressBar*? Для большего подтормаживания? )

**Попутно.**

Не обязательно для каждого макроса создавать отдельные модули. Так можно больше запутаться.

Некоторые процедуры можно объединить в одну. Например, PredpriyatiyePoslednego*. 3 или 4 кода одинаковы, меняются только переменные.

В коде лучше использовать внутреннее имя листа, иначе можно получить сбой после переименования листа хитроруким пользователем.

В процедурах обработки событий листа можно задавать диапазон реагирования. Не нужно будет писать "Если щелкаем на ячейке, в которой нет номера вагона"...

Нужно не очищать строки, а удалять их. Где удаление строк недопустимо, очищать диапазоны. На листе со справками более 35 000 строк пользовательского диапазона (строк с данными - 1221). А это лишний вес файла, лишний диапазон при обработке массивов...

В общем, писать можно много... Автора вопроса это должно радовать - есть куда расти )

Answer (score 1):

Я решил эту проблему, наверное не очень разумным способом ,но это работает! Короче, нужно в корне листа который не прокручивается колесиком в процедуре по активации прописать активацию данного листа, все что знаю перепробовал и только это помогло.И еще, работает это после того как выделите любую ячейку на выбранном листе.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что проблема решилась усилиями работников Майкрософт. Видимо обновления Офиса сделали свое дело. ОС Windows 10, Офис 2016 - заработало без моего вмешательства!